# javascript, CSS and PHP folder tree

Tags: javascript, php, css, treeview, directory-structure

I am making a folder tree by javascript and PHP.

That is my PHP code:

```
function getSubDirectories($dirName) {

    $ffs = scandir($dirName);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;

    echo '<ul class = "mainFolder">';

    foreach($ffs as $ff) {
        if(is_dir($dirName.'/'.$ff)) {
            echo "<li class = 'subFolder'  ><span class = 'subFolderSpan' onclick = hideFolder(this.id) id = ".$ff.">".$ff;
            getSubDirectories($dirName.'/'.$ff);
        } 
        echo '</span></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
        
    }
    //getSubDirectories("../deneme");
?>
```

Here my javascript code:

```
function hideFolder(ID) {

    var elementID = ID;
    
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var firstChildOfelement = element.firstElementChild;
    console.log(ID);
    //console.log(element.childNodes);

    if (firstChildOfelement.style.display == "none") {
        firstChildOfelement.style.display = "";
    }   
    else {
        firstChildOfelement.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

And this is my CSS file

```
.rootFolder {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.subFolder {
    /*margin-left: 2.5em;*/
    /* list-style: square inside url("Folder-icon.png");*/

    padding-left:2.5em;
    /*list-style-type: disc;*/
}

.mainFolder {
    padding:0 ;
}

  .subFolderSpan:hover {
      background-color: aquamarine;
  }
```

My problem is that: when I am on an list item, all parents change their background color. Not just the item that I am on. This is CSS problem. I tried make a unordered list structure without PHP, then the problem did not occur.

[a screenshot for CSS problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUqRM.png)

when I click a span, onclick affect does not work. I got this error

```
folderTree.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstElementChild' of null
    at hideFolder (folderTree.js:7)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (getFolders.php:15)
```

If I write same code on console, it is working.

Thank for your helps...

Comment: The `this.id` argument that you pass to the `onclick` event function `hideFolder` doesn't exist because you don't have any `id` attribute for your `<li>` element. Add a dynamic ID there or use a different approach (e.g. passing only `this`). Also you're missing quotes/double quotes to enclose your `onclick` event

Comment: @AndreaOlivato actually it has id attribute as I try something on the code, I might delete it. I will edit it, id attribute is belong to span element. Quotes/double quotes were not problem, it is working.

Comment: Passing `this.id` and then getting the element via that id, is kinda superfluous - you could have just passed `this`, then you have the reference to the element already, and don’t need to fetch it via id.

Comment: The HTML structure you are creating there probably doesn’t make the most sense. `<li><span>` will only exist if the current item was a directory - but the closing `</span></li>` you output in any case. So for any directory that does not contain _only_ directories, the numbers of opening and closing tags certainly won’t match.

Comment: I changed span tag but it is not working again. I will look at the javascript one after css problem. @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. After I edit this section:

```
 echo '<ul class = "mainFolder">';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        
        if(is_dir($dirName.'/'.$ff)){
            echo "<li class = 'subFolder'  ><span class = 'subFolderSpan' onclick = hideFolder(this.id) id = ".$ff.">".$ff;
            getSubDirectories($dirName.'/'.$ff);
        } 
        echo '</span></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

like that:

```
 echo '<ul class = "mainFolder">';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        
        if(is_dir($dirName.'/'.$ff)){
            echo "<li class = 'subFolder'  ><span class = 'subFolderSpan' onclick = hideFolder(this.id) id = ".$ff.">".$ff."</span>";
            getSubDirectories($dirName.'/'.$ff);
        } 
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```